# Java class member construction

Tags: java

I'm just learning java out of a what seems to be an excellent book, but I'm having a problem following one of the examples. In the code that follows, I'm obviously missing a step in using a member variable of a simple class. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    String color;
}

class DogsExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dog [] myDogs = new Dog[3];

    myDogs[0].name = "Rover";
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it causes a null pointer exception where I assign a value to the name member variable:

```
$ java DogsExample
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DogsExample.main(DogsExample.java:11)
```

Why can't I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, when you create an array, it is automatically filled with `null` values (unless you are using an array of primitives, in which case the array is filled with zeros).

What you are doing is accessing a null value and trying to get a field of it. Your code is essentially performing `null.name = "Rover"`. Set `myDogs[0]` to a valid instance, or you'll get a NullPointerException.

You can create a new instance of Dog in the element like this:

```
myDogs[0] = new Dog();
```

Or you can do it when you make the array, like this:

```
Dog[] myDogs = {new Dog(), new Dog(), new Dog()};
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, now I understand the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is an empty array, three elements long. It's like three kennels in a row, with no dogs in them. You have to put a `Dog` in each kennel before you can give the `Dog` a name:

```
myDogs[0] = new Dog();
myDogs[0].name = "Rover";
```

Repeat for `myDogs[1]` and `myDogs[2]`.

Comment: I was going to upvote, but I don't really like this post-unfinished-answer-just-to-be-first-and-then-add-code-later attitude..

Comment: @Niklas This is common on Stack Exchange. It is referred to as the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Unfortunately, this is the most effective method of securing the upvotes, which are important for more than reputation.

Comment: @NiklasB., maybe we can take this discussion over to meta. Personally, what's good enough for Jon Skeet is good enough for me :)

Comment: @Ernest: Hehe, you're probably right :P This has been discussed often enough, I think. I just noticed that you already had the colon after the end of your last sentence without anything after it in your first revision, which didn't make any sense without the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You created an array of the Dog type, but didn't put any Dog objects in it.  Dog[0] is `null`.

```
Dog [] myDogs = new Dog[3];

myDogs[0] = new Dog(); // <== This populates the array with a new Dog object

myDogs[0].name = "Rover";
```